# jQuery $windowload function dose not work on wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use this code on my index.php file on wordpress all function is work correctly just this function dose not work correctly.I already used wp enque script so now i dont know whats the problem i need your help....

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel();
    $("#flexiselDemo2").flexisel({
        enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
        responsiveBreakpoints: {
            portrait: {
                changePoint: 480,
                visibleItems: 1
            },
            landscape: {
                changePoint: 640,
                visibleItems: 2
            },
            tablet: {
                changePoint: 768,
                visibleItems: 3
            }
        }
    });

    $("#flexiselDemo3").flexisel({
        visibleItems: 5,
        animationSpeed: 1000,
        autoPlay: true,
        autoPlaySpeed: 3000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
        responsiveBreakpoints: {
            portrait: {
                changePoint: 480,
                visibleItems: 1
            },
            landscape: {
                changePoint: 640,
                visibleItems: 2
            },
            tablet: {
                changePoint: 768,
                visibleItems: 3
            }
        }
    });

    $("#flexiselDemo4").flexisel({
        clone: false
    });

});
```

Comment: replace '$' with 'jQuery'

Comment: @Haris Doesn't make any difference!

Comment: change `$(window).load(function () {` to `jQuery(function($){`. If that doesn't work, check the console and post your error.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a conflict happen between `jQuery` and `Wordpress here, try to convert`$`to`jQuery` or use:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Your code here
});
```

or wrap all of your current jQuery code inside a closure:

```
(function($){
    // Your code here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: sorry to say i already change $>jquery and use both above function but its not correct

Comment: no all things right just this function dose not work